# Raspberry stuck in PyCharm User Agreement

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, pycharm

Ive downloaded an extracted Pycharm on my Raspberry Pi. The problem is, when i start the pycharm.sh script, the pycharm user agreement window appears, but stays stuck with a lightblue background.

[image]

Comment: This site is for questions related to programming. Questions about installing or using software might better fit on https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or maybe other specific sites depending on the OS you use. Please add details about the type of Raspberry Pi and the OS and OS version.

Comment: Okay, i will post my question there

Comment: link to MaxB's question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137633/raspberry-stuck-in-pycharm-user-agreement